# Flask URL routes using blueprint are not working, return 404 http code

Tags: python, flask

I am facing a problem with flask url routing; it seems routes are not working as expected.

1. Under `project/src/views.py`, I have the following sample routes

   ```
   from flask import (Flask,request,jsonify,Blueprint)
   my_view = Blueprint('my_view', __name__)

   @my_view.route('/',methods=("GET",))
   @my_view.route('/index',methods=("GET",))
   def index():
       ....
       <return response code here> 

   @my_view.route("/key/<inp1>/<inp2>", methods=("POST","GET"))
   def getKey(inp1=None, inp2=None):
       ....
       <return response code here>
   ```
2. Now, under `project/src/app.py`, I have the following code

   ```
   from ../src.views import my_view 

   my_app = Flask("myappname")
   my_app.register_blueprint(my_view)
   my_app.run(debug=True,host=APP_IP,port=APP_PORT)
   ```

Now, when I access the URL `http://ip:port/index` or `http://ip:port/key...` with valid parameters, it returns 404, with the message "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." I believe mentioned routes are not working.

Comment: Team,  any suggestions? As well, how do we know as whats happening when this endpoint was hit? Anyway, we can add few debug statements to  the code.

Comment: 2024 and still without solution?

Answer (score 4):

The **first issue** spotted is with your `methods` parameter. It expects a list/tuple but you're passing a string ('GET'). Change to `methods=('GET', )`. Note the comma after 'GET' here. Or to avoid potential confusion in the future, use `methods=['GET']`

The **second issue** is the way you're import `my_view` in `app.py`. Since `views.py` and `app.py` are in the same directory, and you're starting your flask app inside that directory, you can just do:

```
from views import my_view
```

However you should look into structuring your app as a [Python Package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

The **third issue** is a missing `from flask import Flask`. Maybe you overlooked this when you posted your code.

I tested your code with the above fixes and it works like it should.

EDIT: Thanks to @dirn for pointing out that tuples are accepted for methods parameter.

Comment: Tuples are okay. The problem is that `('GET')` is not a tuple, it's a string; `('GET',)` is a tuple.

Comment: Just to be clear, when i run the app.py with out blueprints and keeping all routes and business logic in same code file app.py, these are working, so decorators, arguments, business code is not the issue i believe, after testing i just moved some stuff to views.py as a good project structure and added blueprints, thereafter the issue started.